# Scrapy doesn't find custom function

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I have implemented my own function for excluding urls which contain certain words. However when I call it inside my parse method, Scrapy tells me that the function is not defined, even though it is. I didn't use the rule object since I get the Urls I want to scrape from an api. Here is my setup:

```
class IbmSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
       ...

   def checkUrlForWords(text): 
        ...
        return flag

   def parse(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body)
        results = data.get('resultset').get('searchresults').get('searchresultlist')
        for result in results:
            url = result.get('url')
            if (checkUrlForWords(url)==True): continue
        yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_content, meta={'title': result.get('title')})
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is defined inside your class. Use:

```
IbmSpiderSpider.checkUrlForWords(url)
```

Your function looks like a static method, you can use the appropriate decorator to call it with `self.checkUrlForWords`:

```
class IbmSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
       ...

   @staticmethod
   def checkUrlForWords(text): 
        ...
        return flag

   def parse(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body)
        results = data.get('resultset').get('searchresults').get('searchresultlist')
        for result in results:
            url = result.get('url')
            if (self.checkUrlForWords(url)==True): continue
        yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_content, meta={'title': result.get('title')})
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `self.checkUrlForWords` since this is method inside class. Usage of plain `checkUrlForWords` will lead to errors. Just add `self` to method attributes and calling.

```
def checkUrlForWords(self, text): 
        ...
        return flag
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also define your function outside from your class in the same `.py` file:

```
def checkUrlForWords(text): 
    ...
    return flag

class IbmSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
       ...
   def parse(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body)
        results = data.get('resultset').get('searchresults').get('searchresultlist')
        for result in results:
            url = result.get('url')
            if (checkUrlForWords(url)==True): continue
        ....
```